# Access 2010 Query for current month

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have built an Access database to keep track of Quality Assurance Monitors for our team.  Our team has several leads that oversee the reps on the team.

I want to build a query the will return all of the QA's for a specified lead for the current month.  I have criteria for specifying a lead and have got that to work, but every time I try to set the criteria for the current month, it ends up returning no results.

Searching Google has repeatedly suggested using the `Month(Now())`, but that doesn't work either.

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 1):

Answer inspired by @Justin-rentmeester but refined to always return the desired results:

Add the following to the `WHERE` clause of your query:

```
MyDateField BETWEEN    
DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1) 
AND
DateAdd("s", -1, DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1))), DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)
```

I reccommend that you use SQL view to add this criterium.

This approach also works with dates that include times, and with months with less than 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on criteria field- Between Date()-Day(Now()-1) And Date()

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**I edit my answer!**

Assuming `workdate` is your date field.

A shorter `where clause` can be

```
 where Year(workDate) = Year(Date()) and Month(workDate) = Month(Date())
```

This will filter all records for the current month.

If you want to further filter for records up to  today add

```
and workdate <= Date()
```

This may not be necessary if you are not storing future dated records in your table.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That didn't work either.  I did find that using Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1) And Date() seemed to accomplish what I'm looking for.  Is this just the longer, more difficult way of saying Month(Now)?  If so, any ideas on what's different?

Comment: You don't get it. `Month` returns the month (number), `DateSerial` returns a date value.

Comment: Saju's answer should work, because he compares year numbers with year numbers and month numbers with month numbers. However, you cannot compare a number with a date! So `Month(Now) = someDate` cannot work, because the expressions on both sides of the equals sign have a different data type.

Answer (score -2):

To do this in the Design view in Access, select all of the columns you want in the report and on the date column you want to restrict to the current month, for the Criteria put: Between

```
DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)
```

And

```
DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),31)
```

Comment: This answer causes problems for months that don't have 31 days. `DateSerial(2017, 2, 31)` returns the 3rd of march 2017, thus it can return posts that are outside of the month. Also, datetime objects with a time part on the 31th of a month will be greater than your last criteria